Error 'The transaction log for database is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP' during replication
I've set up replications on the database server. DatabaseA is to be replicated to another server.
While executing the distribution agent, I get the following error message.

The transaction log for database 'DatabaseA' is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'.

I went ahead with the usual suggestions

Set recovery model to "Full" (It was set to Simple)
Took a full backUp of the database
Took a transaction Log BackUp
Shrank the transactional log

And still am getting that error.  Does anyone have any advice on how to resolve it?  Am I not following the remediation steps right?
